# Accessing FormControl elements directly instead of using form.get

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

Given the following code snippet within a `FormGroup`:

`<input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName="email" placeholder="email">`

Is there anyway I can access the value of this input within the template (not from the .ts file) using a reference variable (for example) instead of using `form.get('email')...` and would there be any advantages to that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a reference in your `component` file:

```
group: FormGroup;
emailCtrl: FormControl;
// other controls

ngOnInit() {
  this.emailCtrl = this.formBuilder.control(
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ]);

  this.group = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: this.emailCtrl
    // other controls
  });
}
```

So, in template:

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="group">
  <input type="email" placeholder="email" [formControl]="emailCtrl">
  email value = {{emailCtrl.value}}
</form>
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ACXX8baq9bTMCJrAgTxa?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping I could reference the component in the template directly using `formControlName` or some other attribute but without having to create a property in my component for it.